# ASP.NET MVC displaying foreign key value

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I have a phonebook application with the following two entity classes:

Contact.cs

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String fName { get; set; }
    public String lName { get; set; }
    public String phoneNumber { get; set; }
    public PhoneType phoneType { get; set; }

}
```

and

PhoneType.cs

```
public class PhoneType
{
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String phoneType { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; } = new List<Contact>();
}
```

My index page displays the contact name and phonenumber but I would also like it to display the phonetype.

I tried different things but my phonetype is blank.

Right now in my index view I have the following code:

```
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.phoneType.phoneType)
</td>
```

But the phonetype is displaying blank.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting them from Entity Framework you might not be including the other class:

```
var contacts = _context.Contact.Include(p => p.phoneType).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried putting this code in my controller but it still doesnt work.

Comment: Well I looked at your other questions, so if you copy my code exactly then it won't work, but maybe this will  - var contacts = context.Contacts.Include(p => p.phoneType).ToList(); You might need to also just specify it with a string like var contacts = context.Contacts.Include("phonetype").ToList();